# DataTable: why fixed width do not work when i use column Group?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

This is my column Group, before I use column group fixed width was working. 
How to fix width ?

```
 <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row >
        <p:column rowspan="2"  headerText="Accumed-Id"  filterStyle="width: 70px;" filterBy="#{item.claimId}"  filterMatchMode="contains"/>
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Alert" style="width: 200px !important; " />
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Severity" style="width: 50px !important;"  /> 
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Short Description"   /> 
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Long Description" /> 
        <p:column rendered="#{validateClaimsController.checkRulesByPass}" style="width:10%" colspan="3" headerText="ByPassed" />
    </p:row>
    <p:row >
        <p:column width="100" rendered="#{validateClaimsController.checkRulesByPass}" headerText="In" />
        <p:column rendered="#{validateClaimsController.checkRulesByPass}" headerText="Note" />
        <p:column rendered="#{validateClaimsController.checkRulesByPass}" headerText="By" />
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

Comment: Can you send the rest of the datatable code

Comment: when i add  resizableColumns="false", tableStyle="table-layout: fixed !important;" in data table tag it works, thanks

Comment: always state version info